# The list is moving when one item is selected

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a list of menu items. The goal is for the font to become bold when I select one of the items. However, when I do this, the other items shift slightly. I tried to add `width`, but then I have different spacing between items. How can I make these items remain static when one of them is selected?

[image]

```
return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center gap-5 justify-between max-w-7xl m-auto text-xl">
        {genres.map((genre, index) => {
          return (
            <button
              key={index}
              className={`${
                selectedGenre === index ? 'font-bold' : 'font-normal'
              }`}
              onClick={() => onSelect(index)}
            >
              {genre.toUpperCase()}
            </button>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

By adding `w-full` class to all buttons, you're ensuring that they all have the same width regardless of their content or whether they are selected.

```
return (
  <div>
    <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between max-w-7xl m-auto text-xl">
      {genres.map((genre, index) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={index}
            className={`${
              selectedGenre === index ? 'font-bold' : 'font-normal'
            } w-full`} // Add w-full to ensure all buttons have the same width
            onClick={() => onSelect(index)}
          >
            {genre.toUpperCase()}
          </button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I face similar problem before, I just you the same font-weight with darker color when active

Answer (score -1):

Because button is an inline-block element and doesn't have an explicit width, so it shrink-wraps the content.

To solve it, give the button element a fixed width and set style of it to block. Or use a monospace font.